# Поисковая система

Tags: php

Откуда поисковые системы типо  [webalta](http://webalta.ru)  берут списки сайтов

Comment: Мне кажется, что гуглят.

Comment: Илья Жавнерчик (это его настоящее имя), брось эту идею - создать свою поисковую систему! Она мёртвая!!!

Comment: @Дарья Сереброва, **you are not welcome here.**

Comment: Ну, а что?

Comment: Имхо, зря минусуете. Вопрос сам по себе интересный для многих начинающих веб-прогеров. А то, что задал его человек, особо не вникающий в полученные ответы, уже вторично. Хм....А можно минусовать уважение, не минусуя рейтинг вопроса или ответа?

Comment: @zenith, а я вообще не понимаю смысла минусования **вопросов**.

Answer (score 3):

Вебальта мёртвая система.

А так вообще у поисковой системы есть интерфейс по которому можно сообщить о новом сайте, для яндекса это, наприрмер, http://webmaster.yandex.ru/addurl.xml.

Также у поисковой системы есть робот, который регулярно анализирует контент сайтов, найдя новые ссылки, переходит по ним и если сайта нет в базе добавляет его.

Comment: А где они(роботы) ищять эти сайты)))) И есть ли исхдники таких роботов или нужно делать самому(на чём они сделаны )

Comment: Их нужно написать. А сайты берут из списка сайтов. Проходят по сайту, видят новые ссылки на другие сайты и те сайты добавляют в базу, парсят сайт и ищут новые сайты. И так циклом.

Comment: А где онищут сайты по ip чтоли

Comment: @Дарья Сереброва, глупый вопрос, читай внимательно выше!!!

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, для начала надо учить матчасть.
Начни [с этого](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0).
А дальше сам найдёшь :)  
Извините за каламбур.